# How to use STOMP heartbeats in web and spring?

Tags: spring, stomp, heartbeat

Now I'm using stomp to connect from web to server.

I know STOMP has a heartbeat mechanism after v1.1, also I've already set it successfully. But I don't know how to detect/catch PING/PONG frame and handle it.

The code in web like this:

```
    this.stomp = Stomp.client(this.wsUrl);
    this.stomp.heartbeat.outgoing = 5000;
    this.stomp.heartbeat.incoming = 5000;
    this.stomp.connect({}, (frame: any) => {
    // ...
    }, (error: any) => {
    // ...
    });
```

The code in server like this. we use spring stomp.

```
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic")
            .setTaskScheduler(new DefaultManagedTaskScheduler())
            .setHeartbeatValue(new long[] {5000, 5000});
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/signal");
}
```

I can see PING/PONG frame printed in the console panel in chrome.

Comment: did you find any solution for your question? I am also facing same problem in my project? I can't understand how to use it in spring?

Comment: No, I am still sending heartbeat by myself.

Comment: You are sending it yourself? I thought the libraries are sending it? What do you want to do with the ping/pong frame?

Comment: I expect it can automatically disconnect or reconnect according to my configuration. But it does nothing but send a ping/ping message. Even I don't know how to write trigger about the message.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution by any chance? I'm stuck at the same problem. Ping messages are being sent but I don't know how to handle timeout.